# Normal Operators (Obsolete!)

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces

**Problem**

Given a Hilbert space $\mathcal{H}$.

Consider a normal operator:
$$N:\mathcal{D}(T)\to\mathcal{H}:\quad N^*N=NN^*$$

Construct the operator:
$$A:=N(1+N^*N)^{-1}\in\mathcal{B}(\mathcal{H})$$

Then it is normal:
$$A^*\in\mathcal{B}(\mathcal{H}):\quad A^*A=AA^*$$
How can I prove this?

**Disclaimer**

This question became obsolete due to: [Transform](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1245387/79762)
I kept it open for the sake of respect for TAE's answer.
Also it may serve as a manual to handling such problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By the other thread:
$$WN\subseteq NW\quad WN^*\subseteq N^*W$$

And formally it holds:
$$\psi\in\mathcal{D}(N^*):\quad A^*\psi=WN^*\psi$$

So a calculation gives:
$$AA^*\psi=NWWN^*\psi=WNN^*W\psi=WN^*NW\psi=A^*A\psi\quad(\psi\in\mathcal{D}N^*)$$

But the domain was dense:
$$\overline{\mathcal{D}(N^*)}=\mathcal{H}\implies AA^*=A^*A$$

That finishes the proof.

Answer (score 1):

If $E_N$ is the spectral resolution for $N$, then the following is bounded and normal by the functional calculus:
$$
       N(I+N^{\star}N)^{-1} = \int \frac{\lambda}{1+|\lambda|^{2}}dE_{N}(\lambda).
$$
In line with your comment under this point that you are trying to derive the spectral measure, let's try a different approach.

For any $x$, one has $y=(I+N^{\star}N)^{-1}x \in \mathcal{D}(N^{\star}N)=\mathcal{D}(NN^{\star})$ and, hence, $Ny$ and $N^{\star}y$ are defined. So
$$
   Ax = N(I+N^{\star}N)^{-1}x,\;\;\; Bx = N^{\star}(I+N^{\star}N)^{-1}x
$$
are defined everywhere. $A$ and $B$ are bounded because they are everywhere defined, and easily verified to be closed. If $x \in \mathcal{D}((N^{\star}N)^{2})$, then
$$
                 (I+N^{\star}N)N^{\star}x = N^{\star}(I+NN^{\star})x=N^{\star}(I+N^{\star}N)x.
$$
If $y \in \mathcal{D}(N^{\star}N)$, then $x=(I+N^{\star}N)^{-1}y \in \mathcal{D}((N^{\star}N)^{2})$, and the above gives
$$
      (I+N^{\star}N)N^{\star}(I+N^{\star}N)^{-1}y = N^{\star}y \\
           N^{\star}(I+N^{\star}N)^{-1}y=(I+N^{\star}N)^{-1}N^{\star}y.
$$
Therefore, if $x \in \mathcal{D}(N^{\star}N)$, $y \in \mathcal{H}$,
\begin{align}
      (Bx,y) & = (N^{\star}(I+N^{\star}N)^{-1}x,y) \\
             & = ((I+N^{\star}N)^{-1}N^{\star}x,y) \\
             & = (N^{\star}x,(I+N^{\star}N)^{-1}y) \\
             & = (x,N(I+N^{\star}N)^{-1}y) \\
             & = (x,Ay).
\end{align}
That's enough to prove that $B^{\star}=A$ and $A^{\star}=B$ because $\mathcal{D}(N^{\star}N)$ is dense in $\mathcal{H}$. To show that $A$ is normal, keep in mind that $N$ is normal and, therefore,
\begin{align}
     \|Ax\| & =\|N(I+N^{\star}N)^{-1}x\| \\
            & =\|N^{\star}(I+N^{\star}N)^{-1}x\| \\
            & =\|A^{\star}x\|.
\end{align}
So $A$ is normal and $A^{\star}=B$ is normal.

Comment: Oh I should have mentioned I'm trying to construct the spectral measure by this construction...

Comment: @Freeze_S : I added a different argument, but forgot to ping you.

Comment: No worry I'd have come by anyway... ;)

Comment: Im struggling to prove closedness; can you elaborate on it, please?

Comment: If $\{ x_{n} \}$ converges to $x$, and $\{ N(I+N^{\star}N)^{-1}x_n \}$ converges to $y$, then $\{ z_n=(I+N^{\star}N)^{-1}x_n\}$ converges to $(I+N^{\star}N)^{-1}x$ (why?) and $\{ Nz_n \}$ converges to $y$. Because $N$ is closed, then $y = N\lim_{n}z_n = N(I+N^{\star}N)^{-1}x$.

Comment: Ah because we have $ST$ with $S$ closed and $T$ bounded. Thanks!!!

Comment: I'm so sorry that I need to change the construction... :/
Do you mind adapting your answer?

Comment: @Freeze_S : If you want a new construction, please post a new problem.

Comment: Ok I will rename this one here since outdated, that's fine?