# Normal Operators: Transform

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces

Given a Hilbert space $\mathcal{H}$.

Consider a normal operator:
$$N:\mathcal{D}(N)\to\mathcal{H}:\quad N^*N=NN^*$$

Construct the operator:
$$Q:=(1+N^*N)^{-1}:\quad Z:=N\sqrt{Q}$$

> Then it is normal:
>   $$Z\in\mathcal{B}(\mathcal{H}):\quad Z^*Z=ZZ^*$$

How can I prove this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Meanwhile I got it...*

**Square Root**

It is a well-know result:
$$Q\in\mathcal{B}(\mathcal{H}):\quad Q=Q^*$$

The range includes:
$$\mathcal{R}Q=\mathcal{D}(1+N^*N)=\mathcal{D}N^*N$$

One has the bound:
$$\langle Q^{-1}\psi,\psi\rangle=\langle(1+N^*N)\psi,\psi\rangle=\|\psi\|^2+\|N\psi\|^2\geq0$$

So the numerical range:
$$\mathcal{W}(Q^{-1})\geq0\implies\mathcal{W}(Q)\geq0$$

For bounded operators:
$$Q\in\mathcal{B}(\mathcal{H}):\quad\sigma(Q)\subseteq\overline{\mathcal{W}(Q)}$$

Thus the square root exists:
$$\sqrt{Q}\in\mathcal{B}(\mathcal{H}):\quad\sqrt{Q}=\sqrt{Q}^*$$

Especially range and kernel:
$$\mathcal{H}\supseteq\overline{\mathcal{R}\sqrt{Q}}\supseteq\overline{\mathcal{R}Q}=\mathcal{H}$$
$$(0)\subseteq\mathcal{N}\sqrt{Q}\subseteq\mathcal{N}Q=(0)$$

*(This is basic so far.)*

**Operator**

One has the bound:
$$\|NQ\varphi\|^2=\langle N^*NQ\varphi,Q\varphi\rangle\leq\langle N^*NQ\varphi,Q\varphi\rangle+\langle Q\varphi,Q\varphi\rangle=\langle\varphi,Q\varphi\rangle=\|\sqrt{Q}\varphi\|^2$$

The operator is closed:
$$\sqrt{Q}\in\mathcal{B}(\mathcal{H}):\quad\quad N=\overline{N}\implies Z=\overline{Z}$$

By uniform extension:
$$\|Z\restriction_{\mathcal{R}\sqrt{Q}}\|\leq1\implies Z\in\mathcal{B}(\mathcal{H})$$

Especially the range lies in:
$$\mathcal{D}Z=\mathcal{H}\implies\mathcal{R}\sqrt{Q}\subseteq\mathcal{D}N$$
*(Domain is unclear a priori!)*

**Polynomials**

Here regard elements:
$$\varphi,\chi\in\mathcal{D}N=\mathcal{D}N^*$$

Exploit the selfadjoint inverse:
$$\langle NQ\varphi,\chi\rangle=\langle Q\varphi,N^*(1+N^*N)Q\chi\rangle=\langle Q\varphi,(1+N^*N)N^*Q\chi\rangle=\langle QN\varphi,\chi\rangle$$

Thus a calculation reveals:
$$\langle\sqrt{Q}N\varphi,\chi\rangle=\lim_n\langle Q_nN\varphi,\chi\rangle=\lim_n\langle NQ_n\varphi,\chi\rangle=\lim_n\langle Q_n\varphi,N^*\chi\rangle=\langle N\sqrt{Q}\varphi,\chi\rangle$$

Hence on operator level:
$$N1=1N\quad NQ\supseteq QN\quad NQ^k\supseteq Q^kN\quad N\sqrt{Q}\supseteq\sqrt{Q}N$$

*(The analogous hold for adjoint.)*

**Normality**

Formally the adjoint acts as:
$$\langle Z\varphi,\psi\rangle=\langle\varphi,\sqrt{Q}N^*\psi\rangle\quad(\psi\in\mathcal{D}N^*)$$

Regard dense elements:
$$\varphi\in\mathcal{R}\sqrt{Q}\subseteq\mathcal{D}N=\mathcal{D}N^*$$

Remind also that:
$$\sqrt{Q}\varphi\in\mathcal{R}Q=\mathcal{D}N^*N=\mathcal{D}NN^*$$

Thus one derives:
$$Z^*Z\varphi=\sqrt{Q}N^*N\sqrt{Q}\varphi=\sqrt{Q}NN^*\sqrt{Q}\varphi\\
=N\sqrt{Q}N^*\sqrt{Q}\varphi=N\sqrt{Q}\sqrt{Q}N^*\varphi=ZZ^*\varphi$$

Concluding normality.

Comment: Do you just use this site to keep track of your homework problems? Your posts are so similar looking I'd almost think they were machine-generated.

Comment: @Math1000: Nope, I hope to get hints resp. answers to my problems... *(I do, really!)* Unfortunately, that happens veery rarely. But I cannot let it go so I come back from time to time with new ideas... *(See time-stamps!)* The machine looking is because I like symmetry... ^^

Comment: @Math1000: Besides, considering these as homework problems is almost an insult... These are mostly my own problems I think about.

Comment: Wasn't trying to be insulting. I just figured a blog would be a better forum for posting problems and your solutions to them than MSE. I'm glad to know you're human and not a bot, though ;)

Comment: @Math1000: Ya I heard that already a couple of times. But I want to keep my stuff together.